# SIFT orientation normalization

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I want to normalize the sift descriptors by rotating them so that the horizontal direction is aligned with the dominant gradient orientation of the patch.

I am using vl_feat library. Is there any way in vl_feat to normalize the sift descriptos?

or

what is the effective way of doing this using matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the ones in VLfeat are already oriented in the dominant gradient direction.

It shows them rotated if you look here: http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html

```
 [f,d] = vl_sift(I) ;
```

f is a Nx4 matrix of keypoints. N being the keypoint indexand the other 4 being, x position, y position, scale, and orientation. d is a Nx128 matrix, where N is the keypoint index, and the 128 dimensions belong to the SIFT descriptor.

---

If all of your images are rotated upright, it is actually beneficial to not use rotational invariance. See this paper which assume a gravity vector: https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/9548/2009-Efficient-representation-of-local-geometry-for-large-scale-object-retrieval.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am not sure about the vl_sift whether it is rotated or not. I am trying to match the feature points from one image with another image. In that case do you think I dont need to rotate the sift features to its dominant orientation?

Comment: You currently have orientation-invariance (because vl_sift does this by default). My second point was: right now, the consensus in the literature is that *if your images are all upright* then it is better to leave the descriptor unrotated. Now, if you want to unrotate your SIFT descriptors you will have to look in the tutorial on the webpage I sent you. VL_sift allows for a Frames argument, taking the keypoints (the fc variable: x,y,scale,orientation) that you want to describe, and computes a sift descrtiptor for each of those. Set orientation to 0 if you want the gravity vector.